# PHP inside CSS stylesheet

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am trying to insert a shortcode inside CSS file but i am unable to achieve it. Don't know where I am going wrong.

I am inserting below code inside my style.css file:

```
div#cuzd-dispatch-general-v {
    display: <?php echo do_shortcode('[dispatch_date_hide]'); ?> ;
    }
```

***OUTPUT:***

```
div#cuzd-dispatch-general-v {
display: <?php echo do_shortcode('[dispatch_date_hide]');
}
```

Output as Image: http://oi61.tinypic.com/2uiyd4x.jpg

Comment: The css must be in a `.php` file.

Comment: You'd need to tell your webserver to process CSS as PHP. Instead, couldn't you just have multiple rules using your the shortcode as a CSS class, then add the class to the HTML based on the shortcode using PHP, or whatever templating you're using.

Comment: Probably your goal is to dynamically create a css file, since a css file itself cannot contain any dynamic elements like php code. You can do that by implementing a php file that outputs css rules (instead of the usual html markup). You then reference that php file just like any static css file.

Comment: This question has been asked a number of times in a number of different ways, on SO and on other websites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this code in your header.php inside `<style> </style>`

```
div#cuzd-dispatch-general-v {
    display: <?php echo do_shortcode('[dispatch_date_hide]'); ?> ;
}
```

Comment: Sorry. I dont have much reputation. I tried but it failed.

Answer (score 2):

PHP code cannot be interpreted inside a .css file so your php code will be showen as a plain text, add the part of your code in the style tag of your php file.